# Definitions of split injection and split surjection

Tags: homological-algebra

Let $f: C_\bullet \to D_\bullet$ be chain map between chain complexes. What does it mean for $f$ to be a *split injection*? And a *split surjection*?

I am aware of the definitions of [split monomorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+monomorphism) and [split epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism) in an arbitrary category. However, is there a more intuitive definition of split injection or of split surjection in the category of chain complexes of modules (perhaps some definition that involves a direct sum)? I cannot seem to find a good reference.

Comment: How more intuitive than "there exists a left (right) inverse" can it be ?